# How many *very quiteprime* positive integers are there less than 90000?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

A positive integer is *very quiteprime* if it is not divisible by any prime less than $15$. How many *very quiteprime* positive integers are there less than $90000$?

I tried to come up with a pattern but couldn't really find one, any help?

Comment: If you really wanted, you could have a computer search for you.

Comment: This is a question for the PROMYS summer camp entrance exam. I'm sure the committee will take a dim view of solutions found on the Internet.